# How to Replace ASCII Characters as "\u0010" From String in c#

Tags: c#, text, ascii

Here i get the text from web browser as String is as following ,

**"\u0010In the following patterns which pattern appears first : \u0003I6U9, RW5S, A2K6"**

for this code is ,

```
HtmlDocument doc = webView.Document;
HtmlElement span = doc.GetElementsByTagName("span")[3]; 
String OrignalText = span.InnerText;
```

Now i wanted to replace ASCII Codes and return text as,

**"In the following patterns which pattern appears first : I6U9, RW5S, A2K6"**

i have tried all the answers that before discussed on stack overflow but not worked for this , 
for example i have tried ,

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(string)

System.Uri.UnescapeDataString(string)
```

and

```
string DecodeEncodedNonAsciiCharacters( string value ) {
    return Regex.Replace(
        value,
        @"\\u(?<Value>[a-zA-Z0-9]{4})",
        m => {
            return ((char) int.Parse( m.Groups["Value"].Value, NumberStyles.HexNumber )).ToString();
        } );
}
```

so on... But not worked any of those. so please help me.

Comment: How do you verify that you get that string exactly as that? What tool are you using to look at the string?

Comment: I have debug my application from visual .net....so string is exact as i mentioned.

Comment: That probably means the string doesn't actually contain the literal characters `\u0010` but instead just 1 character that the **debugger** chose to escape to make it visible. Try doing a simple string replace `string.Replace("\u0010", "<odd character>");`

Comment: Firstly i have tried this as replace the char, but not worked. Secondly, it dose not have any problem with **debugger** coz i have tried to store this string into database of access, and it was denied as ascii character.

Comment: I would recommend logging the String to the output window, the debugger will escape some chars.

Comment: I can't relate to Access not accepting the string since you have neither asked about that nor have you told us what error message Access gives you.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - While inserting at access it shows **syntax error**.and sorry for not mentioning this part in question.

Comment: @Campl3r - As per you suggestion i have tried to assign that text to label but debugger not escaped any ascii character.

Comment: "Syntax error"? Are you concatenating strings to build up an sql?